# sudo password incorrect all of a sudden

Tags: password, sudo

```
sudo ls
```

All of a sudden it says password incorrect. I am 100% sure of my password. I don't know what happened. Hacked ?

Comment: Type your password plain into the shell (you can transpose characters). It might be a keyboard layout / character set related issue you will be able to notice this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you verified your password is correct by authenticating through the GUI? An easy way is to go to System Preferences > Accounts and click the lock icon. Also, verify that your user account has not lost administrative privileges (you can do this from the same preference pane). If you've lost administrative privileges the issue may be related to something else.

Comment: It got unlocked. So the password didnt get changed. Anyhow, I closed terminal and restarted it, and its all working. Thanks.